# Overly complicated excel vlookup very slow

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have a worksheet with possibly hundreds of columns that I am trying to create smaller reports from.

I created a dynamic vlookup to build the table, but the results are very slow and I am looking for a better solution.

[Sheet1] B2 sample formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,IF({1,0},INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A$1,Data!$1:$1,0),1,,"Data")&":"&ADDRESS((MAX((Data!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Data!$A:$A))),MATCH($A$1,Data!$1:$1,0),1)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(B$1,Data!$1:$1,0),1,,"Data")&":"&ADDRESS((MAX((Data!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Data!$A:$A))),MATCH(B$1,Data!$1:$1,0),1))),2,0)
```

[data] sheet has the data being pulled.

[Sheet1]Row 1 contains headers that match [data] row 1 headers

[Sheet1]Column 1 contains the lookup value

[data] [image: sample]

| ID | First | Last | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First 1 | Last 1 | 101 | 301 |
| 2 | First 2 | Last 2 | 102 | 302 |
| 3 | First 3 | Last 3 | 103 | 303 |

[sheet1] [image: sample]

| id | Last | First | id2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Last 1 | First 1 | 101 |
| 3 | Last 3 | First 3 | 103 |

Comment: I may be missing something, but INDEX seems perfect here, for Sheet1!B2: `=INDEX(data!$A:$E,MATCH($A2,data!$A:$A,0),MATCH(B$1,data!$1:$1,0))`

Comment: yep, overly complicated for no reason. Had to adjust ,MATCH(B$1,data!$1:$1,0)) to ,MATCH(B$1,data!$1:$1,0)-1) - assuming because row match was b:b

Answer (score 1):

Put the match in the return column:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Data!$A:$E,MATCH(B$1,Data!$A$1:$E$1,0),0)
```

If one has FILTER then:

```
=FILTER(Data!$B:$E,Data!$A:$A=$A2)
```

it will spill to the right the values.